# Why use a robot advisor over ETFs?

Tags: etf, robo-advisor

> One central observation is that the vast majority of Robo-Advisors base their investment approach on ETFs. About 70% of the examined providers even operate on an “ETF-only” approach, to maximize cost-efficiency for highly diversified yet small portfolios.
> ([source](https://www2.deloitte.com/content/dam/Deloitte/de/Documents/financial-services/Robo_No_2.pdf))

To me this seems like a really good deal for the company offering the robo advisor and a really bad deal for the customer. After all, choosing a handful of index based funds in various geographic regions is not a complicated operation and will reflect the overall market performance quite well while maintaining a good diversity.

Is there any good reason to pay a fee of typically 0.5-1% for a robo advisor?

Comment: As with any service a broker offers voluntarily, the they do so because it's a good deal for the company. I agree with your criticism: robo-advisors are completely superfluous. Of course, if someone *wants* an actively managed portfolio and has more money than time…

Comment: I think some robo advisors offer automatic tax loss harvesting on some accounts, which I find a little complicated to do myself— is that worth 0.5-1%? maybe? I think Betterment matches or slightly outperforms returns from a straight vanguard index fund in many years. Others like wealthsimple are garbage (IMO) because they’re not seeing a return anywhere close to the index.

Answer (score 1):

**If you already have the necessary knowledge** to create and rebalance over time a portfolio that is appropriate for you and your financial goals, then you shouldn't pay anyone for such advice.  In this case you could

**(A) just get a** Vanguard, or the like, **target retirement date fund.**

**(B) do it all yourself** with ETFs or mutual funds or whatever else you wanted.

**If you don't have all of the necessary knowledge, then a robo-advisor, that will suggest an appropriate portfolio for you and do tax-optimization, can be helpful.**

Many robo-advisors:

- Charge 0.25-0.50% of assets, lower than what you indicated.
- Are geared towards individuals with low assets.  They recommend a portfolio of ETFs where those ETFs typically have low expense ratios AND no minimums AND where those ETFs won't have hidden tax-bombs (in the form of unrealized gains) in them, which is the case with some mutual funds.